# Is it Ok to run 2nd Ethernet cable along the wall right on the top of 1st one?

Tags: ethernet

My router has 5 jacks :) so I want to place another (also flat) Ethernet cable along the same wall. Is it any danger of a quality loss if I place this 2nd cable on the top of the 1st one?
Or I'd better place 2nd one along the floor line (as 1st one goes along the ceiling line)?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

It should be fine - most ethernet cables are fairly resistant to interferance by design , and they're designed to be run together , in fact in corporate settings you might see DOZENS of them being run together.

[image]

I'd suggest whichever option thats logistically easier

Comment: most ethernet cables aren't actually shielded. they eliminate interferece with twisted pair wiring and differential signaling

Answer (score 2):

It will be fine to run them next to each other, especially for home use. Ethernet cables are designed to be very resistant to interference.